# New Syntax similar to Nullabletype from Dropthings?

Tags: c#

I recently downloaded Dropthings portal and found a new syntax in the code.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["t"] ?? string.Empty
```

I was wondering if it is something similar to NULLABLE type where if config... is NULL then this value would be used. Can some one clarify my observation because I could not find an equivalent example in MSDN either?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct,

`a ?? b` means, `a` if `a`  is not null, and `b` if it is

It's kinda the equivalent of `a == null ? b : a`

Answer (score 2):

> The [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173224.aspx) is called the *null-coalescing operator* and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

Example

```
 int? x = null;

 // y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1. 
 int y = x ?? -1;
```

Look at [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx) for simple illustration of this operator.

Answer (score 2):

The `??` in your code is actually a feature that is built into the C# language. It's called the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). You can use it in any C# code.

```
string someValue = null;
Console.WriteLine(someValue ?? "Default Value"); //Default Value
```